# Decouple module error running Django 1.8 project using Django 1.9

Tags: python, django, python-decouple

Currently, I am using latest version of Django 1.9.
I have a project that is written in Django 1.8

When I tried to runserver, I encountered the following error

[image: my first image]

What should I do as I do not want to downgrade to Django 1.8 to run the project?

Edit:
The above problem is due to lack of python-decouple module. After I install decouple module and try to runserver again it gives another error.
[image: image 2]

Answer (score 2):

It is not because you use Django 1.9 that you get that error, it is because that module is not install at the moment. Run `pip install python-decouple` to install the module.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. However I meet another problem as you can see in my edited post.

Comment: @3d510 are you sure that you have a SECRET_KEY variable in your _.env_ file?

Answer (score 0):

In my case installing python-decouple also outside the vitualenv solved the problem.

```
comp@debian:~/Desktop/prj$sudo pip install python-decouple
(venv) comp@debian:~/Desktop/prj$pip install python-decouple
```